# Html-pdf npm uing command line change page size to 300*400

Tags: node.js, pdf, npm, node-modules, node-html-pdf

i have install np in my ubuntu machine to install html-pdf module to use that as a command line input to convert html to pdf.
But that gieve pdf as a different size which i want.
Its breaks that table and show its output to other page 
I have written html page using shell script so i cannot add javascript function to that.
Is there any way to change size using comand line or tool to get that output on one page.
html-pdf input.html output.pdf